# POST Request not being sent correctly?

Tags: java, post, authentication, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to login to "Udemy.com" using the HttpUrlConnection library and here's what I've done.

- Send a "GET" to the login page to get the cookies and the crsftoken.
- Send the "POST" with the cookies obtained before and all the necessary parameters.

I'm getting a "200" response code after sending the POST, **but when I open the HTML that I got from the response it doesn't show me logged in the page**. I've been messing around with the header properties for days but haven't realized what's wrong.

```
public final String urlGet = "https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/?displayType=ajax&display_"
        + "type=popup&showSkipButton=1&returnUrlAfterLogin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2F&next"
        + "=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2F&locale=pt_BR";
public final String urlPost = "https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/?displayType=ajax&display_type"
        + "=popup&showSkipButton=1&returnUrlAfterLogin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%"
        + "2F&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2F&locale=pt_BR";
public final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.97 Safari/537.36";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    UdemyCoupon uc = new UdemyCoupon();
    //  uc.getCouponEachPage();
    //     uc.readArrayList();
    uc.sendGetLogin();
    uc.sendPostLogin();
   // uc.sendGetApplyCoupon();
}

Date date = new Date();
private ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> cookies;
private String cookiesArray[] = new String[100];
private String cookieTotal = "";

public String[] sendGetLogin() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection
            = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(urlGet)
            .openConnection();

    cookies = urlConnection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
        if (cookies.get(i).contains(";")) {
            cookiesArray[i] = cookies.get(i).split(";")[0];
            System.out.println(i + " - " + cookiesArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return cookiesArray;
}

public int sendPostLogin() throws IOException {

    URL obj = new URL(urlPost);

    System.out.println("\nConnecting ...");
    HttpsURLConnection con;
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    int posTokenArray = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
        cookieTotal += cookiesArray[i];
        if (i < cookies.size() - 1) {
            cookieTotal += "; ";
        }

        if (cookiesArray[i].contains("csrftoken")) {
            posTokenArray = i;
        }
    }

    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "pt-PT,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
    con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "128");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieTotal);
    con.setRequestProperty("Host", "www.udemy.com");
    con.setRequestProperty("Origin", "https://www.udemy.com");
    con.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://www.udemy.com/join/login-popup/?displayType=ajax&display_type=popup&showSkipButton=1&returnUrlAfterLogin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2F&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.udemy.com%2F&locale=pt_BR");
    con.setRequestProperty("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    String postParams = "csrfmiddlewaretoken="+ cookiesArray[posTokenArray].split("=")[1] +"&locale=pt_BR&email="+URLEncoder.encode("testudemy@hmamail.com", "UTF-8")+
            "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode("testpass", "UTF-8")+"&submit=Acessar";

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + urlPost);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println("Cookies : " + cookieTotal);
    System.out.println("csrfmiddlewaretoken " + cookiesArray[posTokenArray].split("=")[1]);

    BufferedReader in
            = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    System.out.println(response);

    in.close();
    con.disconnect();

    if (response.toString().contains("Por favor, verifique seu e-mail e sua senha.")) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect email or password!");
        return 0;
    } else if (response.toString().contains("nforme um endereço de email válido")) {
        System.out.println("Email syntax invalid!");
        return 0;
    } else {
        System.out.println("You're in!");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Appreciate any kind of help, thanks.

Comment: You are not specific how you open the page, with browser, in application ?

Comment: @HuTa yes, I use the HTML from the string "response" and then I open it in browser.

Comment: You are aware that there exist something like session in browser ?
You are logging from one source(your app, you should get session id orsomething) and then you are trying to connect with the other(browser) without  being logged in.
http://machinesaredigging.com/2013/10/29/how-does-a-web-session-work/

Comment: You don't have session in browser so it's not logged in, it doesn't matter what link you call. Read article under link from previous comment.
To make this work you have to copy session id from your application to browser.

Comment: @HuTa You're really not understanding, when I send the POST Request, I get the response code and the response code in HTML, I save the HTML in a file, and open it through browser, locally, like "file:///C:/Users/Miguel/Desktop/test.html".